# Wildfly service failed on linux

Tags: linux, wildfly, redhat

**Hello Guys.**

wildfly service it was running. but sudenly stopped with below error:

```
2023-06-14 16:15:41,117 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -Xms8192m -Xmx24576m -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4096m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
2023-06-14 16:15:41,125 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.as: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service
 at rg.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYDR0005: Cannot obtain SHA-1 MessageDigest
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepositoryImpl.<init>(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory.addService(ContentRepository.java:188)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService.start(ApplicationServerService.java:168)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-1 MessageDigest not available
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Was it recently upgraded?

Comment: Maybe you can check on https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5849631 ...